# Como pegar a posição de um elemento <circle> que está dentro de um SVG via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho um SVG que contem, entre outros itens, um elemento `<circle>`.
Consigo manipulá-lo via Javascript, alterando propriedades CSS como `visibility`, mas não consigo pegar a posição dele na tela.

Minha ideia é que, quando o mouse passa sobre determinada `<div>`, outra `<div>` seja exibida tendo como base a posição do `<circle>`.

Tentei utilizar o `offsetTop`, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A posição do circle é definida pelos atributos `cx` e `cy`.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15"></circle>
</svg>
```

```
var circulo = document.querySelector('circle');
circulo.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('cx'), this.getAttribute('cy'));
});
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/6L59khr6/</sup>

Essa posição é relativa à do elemento SVG.

Comment: Assim, para saber a distância do < circle > para o topo da tela eu teria que pegar a coordenada "cy" e depois somar com a coordenada do < svg > ?

Comment: Exatamente, Dionei.

Comment: Referente a pergunta do Dionei, nos comentários, não extamente, pois depende da proporção e escala do SVG.

Comment: Bom, de qualquer forma já é um caminho... Vou trabalhar nisso para resolver meu problema.
Obrigado pela ajuda.